# How to save response value to NSDictionary in Alamofire?

Tags: ios, json, swift, nsdictionary, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire v3.4.1 and i'm getting result of JSON via GET method like this,

```
@IBAction func verifyAction(sender: AnyObject) { 

    let tempEmail: String = "\(emailTxtField.text!)"
    let tempApi : String = appDelegate.apiKey as String 
    var status : String
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.somejsonurl.com/checkEmailExits", parameters: ["APIKey": "\(tempApi)","Email" : "\(tempEmail)"])
            .responseJSON { response in
              print(response.request)  // original URL request
              print(response.response) // URL response
              print(response.data)     // server data
              print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                let JSON = response.result.value         
                let dict1 = JSON!["Result"]
                let dict2 = dict1!!["Status"]
                status = dict2 as! String

    }
```

Now as soon as i assign value to `status` xcode gives me error:

> Variable 'status' captured by a closure before being initialized

Is there a way to store response to `NSDictionary` that can be used in other functions too ? Thanks

Comment: The response is : `{
  "Result": {
    "Status": "0"
  }
}`

Comment: change `var status : String` to `var status = String()` or `var status  =  ""`

Comment: Nope this is not working, xcode is misunderstanding and saying to put `;` in between

Comment: You need to add only one line check my answer.

Comment: @JackSparrow `var status = String()` is all you need  ... if you want to give empty string than initialize like `var status = ""`

Comment: Yes it worked, thanks guys :)

Comment: @JackSparrow glad it helps brother :)

Comment: I was going to accept the answer but it don't let me because you can't accept until 10 mins, and now the answer is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize your object before assigning value to it so declare your `status` object like this

```
var status = String()
```

Or

```
var status: String = ""
```